# Binary Converter Java

Tags: java, while-loop, binary

I am  trying to make a converter that converts decimal into binary, there is a catch tho, I can't use any other loops or statements except

```
while (){}
```

And I can't figure out how to start subtracting the number that fits into the decimal when it can and not using any if statements. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Converter{

static Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

public static void main (String[] args){

  System.out.println ("What is the number in the decimal system that you want to convert to binary?");
  int dec = input.nextInt();
  int sqr = 1024;
  int rem;

  while (dec != 0){

      rem = dec / sqr;
      sqr = sqr / 2;
      System.out.print(rem);
  }  
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Converter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is the number in the decimal system that you want to convert to binary?");
        int dec = input.nextInt();
        int div = 128;

        while (div > 0) {

            System.out.print(dec / div);
            dec = dec % div;
            div >>= 1; // equivalent to div /= 2
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Now, let's go through the code and try to understand what's going on. I'm assuming that the maximum size is 8 bits, so the variable `div` is set to 2<sup>n-1</sup> where n = 1. If you need 16 bits, `div` would be 32768.

The programme starts from that value and attempts to do an **integer** division of the given number by the divider. And the nice thing about it is that it will yield 1 if the number is greater than or equal to the divider, and 0 otherwise.

So, if the number we're trying to convert is 42, then dividing it by 128 yields 0, so we know that the first digit of our binary number is 0.

After that, we set the number to be the **remainder** of the integer division, and we divide the divider by two. I'm doing this with a bit shift right (`div >>= 1`), but you could also use a divider-assignment (`div /= 2`).

By now, the divider is 64, and the number is still 42. If we do the operation again, we again get 0.

At the third iteration, we divide 42 by 32, and this yields 1. So our binary digits so far are `001`. We set the number to be the remainder of the division, which is 10.

Continuing this, we end up with the binary number `00101010`. The loop ends when the divider `div` is zero and there's nothing left to divide.

Try to understand, step by step, how the programme works. It's simple, but it can be very difficult to come up with a simple solution. In this case, it's applied mathematics, and knowing how integer maths work in Java. That comes with experience, which you'll get in due time.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works great, I couldn't figure out what the pattern would be for it to start subtracting the actual divisor from the decimal, but this is great, thank you again.

Comment: It is not true to write it because teacher can ask to print double of that but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some Problem. It is more easier to convert a decimal to binary. fro example:

```
int num = 5;
StringBuilder bin = new StringBuilder();
while (num > 0) {
    bin.append(num % 2);
    num /= 2;
}
System.out.println(bin.reverse());
```

I use StringBuilder to reverse my String and I prefer String because length of binary can be anything. if you use int or long, maybe overflow happen.

### Update

if you you want to use primitive types only, you can do something like this but overflow may happen:

```
    long reversedBin = 0, Bin = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        reversedBin = reversedBin * 10 + (n % 2);
        n /= 2;
    }
    while (reversedBin > 0) {
        Bin = Bin * 10 + (reversedBin % 10);
        reversedBin /= 10;
    }
    System.out.println(Bin);
```

Comment: Alternative for`num /= 2`: `num >>= 1`

Comment: But his doesn't work for negative integers as input. OP needs to clarify if this is required. In case it's required the sign needs to be evaluated additionally.

Comment: @Amin Thank you for your effort, but I can only use a while loop and nothing else, I've made the converter but the teacher says to use while loops only, he told me if it was too complicated, it wouldn't count.

Comment: @Lukyan Do you want to say, you cannot use `StringBuilder`? Then define `bin`as a `String`: `String bin = "";` and in the loop replace the first line by `bin = (num % 2) + bin;` . That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the algorithm to convert from decimal to binary.
Let n be a number in decimal representation:

```
digit_list = new empty stack
while n>0 do
    digit = n%2
    push digit in stack
    n = n/2
end while
binary = new empty string
while digit_list is not empty do
     character = pop from stack
     append character to binary
end while
```

Java provides a generic class Stack that you can use as a data structure. You could also use lists, but remember to take the digits in the inverse order you have calculated them.

Comment: Well, this would work but I need to only use one while loop for the whole thing and i made the converter with a while loop and if statements, but the teacher said it wouldn't count, ut i appreciate your effort to answer my question. Thanks.

Comment: if performances aren't an issue, you could try to declare an empty string that you call 'binary', remove the stack utilization and every iteration you calculate digit, you divide n by 2, and then you do 'binary' = digit+binary;
At the end of the loop you print binary

Comment: int n = 27;
        String binary = "";
        while(n>0) {
         int digit = n%2;
         binary = digit+binary;
         n = n/2;
        }
        System.out.println(binary);

Answer (score 0):

find the base 2 log of the number and floor it to find the number of bits needed. then integer divide by that bits place in 2's power and subtract that from the original number repeat until 0. doesn't work for negative. there are better solutions but this one is mine

```
 int bits = (int) Math.floor(Math.log((double) dec) / Math.log((double) 2));
    System.out.println("BITS:" + bits);
    while (dec > 0) {
        int twoPow = (int) Math.pow((double) 2, (double) bits);
        rem = dec / twoPow;
        dec = dec - rem * twoPow;
        bits--;
        System.out.print(rem);
    }
```

Comment: yes we can use power or more better save power of ten and each loop, multiply with ten. you can make it and reverse it too.